# NSCocoaErrorDomain 513 on iOS8 devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, xcode6, nsfilemanager

I am trying to create a folder using

```
BOOL status =[fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:pathComponent] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
```

`status` is `YES` in iOS7 (device & emulator) , iOS8 (emulator only).

But in iOS 8 devices, the status is `NO` & the error description = `Operation couldn't be completed. Operation not permitted`

The value for  `[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:pathComponent`

in iOS 7

```
/var/mobile/Applications/7AC7128C-1926-41AC-9108-4C85D0D75AE9/HelloWorld.app/../Library/Pages/CSS
```

in iOS 8

```
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/1E2D5D54-2585-4CB9-BD00-24C4BF873421/HelloWorld.app/../Library/Pages/CSS
```

Why I am getting `Operation Couldn't be completed` error in iOS8 devices only?

Answer (score 0):

That code *should* fail on all versions of iOS as you cannot create files/directories in the app bundle.

You need to create files in the app documents, caches, etc directories.

Comment: But it is working perfectly fine on all the other devices prior to iOS 8.

Comment: @TaruniNeema That is *undefined behaviour* as the app bundle should not be messed with once installed.